# How to exclude unnecessary buttons in ALV toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, abap, alv

So, inside the `TOOLBAR` event of the `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` the parameter `E_OBJECT` has the table `MT_TOOLBAR` that I can access to change all the buttons manually.

Is there a better way to include/exclude standard buttons in the toolbar than simply creating them like custom-buttons in the toolbar event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` in class `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` there is also a way.

Define a table of type `UI_FUNCTIONS` and a work area of type `UI_FUNC` :

```
data: lt_exclude type ui_functions,
      ls_exclude type ui_func.
```

Append the attributes of the functions you want to hide to the table:

```
ls_exclude = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_fc_sum.
append ls_exclude to lt_exclude.
```

The attributes of the standard functions all begin with the prefix `MC_FC_`, in addition, there is the prefix `MC_MB_` for an entire menu in the toolbar.

Pass the table using method `set_table_for_first_display` with parameter `it_toolbar_excluding`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` in your code, this might be helpful for you:

```
call function 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
exporting
  i_callback_program       = 'ZPROGRAM'
  i_callback_pf_status_set = 'SET_PF_STATUS'
  it_fieldcat              = it_fieldcat
tables
  t_outtab                 = gt_itab.
```

Your `SET_PF_STATUS` should be like this in order to eliminate some of the buttons you want. In this example I'm eliminating the "SORT_UP" button.

```
form set_pf_status using rt_extab type slis_t_extab.

 data: lv_flag VALUE 'X'.

 if lv_flag is not INITIAL.

   append '&OUP' to rt_extab.

 endif.

 set pf-status 'STANDARD' excluding rt_extab.
endform.                    "set_pf_status
```

Hope it was helpful.

Talha

Answer (score 0):

class lcl_event_alv definition .
public section .

```
methods handle_toolbar for event toolbar of cl_gui_alv_grid
  importing e_object e_interactive sender.
```

class lcl_event_alv implementation .

method handle_toolbar.

```
delete e_object->mt_toolbar where function = '&LOCAL&INSERT_ROW'  or function = '&LOCAL&DELETE_ROW'
                                or function = '&LOCAL&APPEND'     or function = '&LOCAL&COPY'
                                or function = '&LOCAL&PASTE'      or function = '&LOCAL&CUT'
                                or function = '&LOCAL&COPY_ROW'   or function = '&LOCAL&CUT'.
```

endmethod.

data : go_event  type ref to lcl_event_alv.

```
create object go_event .
set handler go_event->handle_toolbar for go_grid1.

call method go_grid1->set_table_for_first_display
  exporting
    is_layout       = gd_layout
    is_variant      = value disvariant( report = sy-repid handle = 'GO_GRID1' )
    i_save          = 'A'
  changing
    it_fieldcatalog = gt_fcat1
    it_outtab       = gt_items1.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).